# objective-c merge videos with texts

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, text, merge

I have to record a video which contains n parts, and I want to insert a different text for every part of video.

I've read the guide of avfoundation of apple, and done some "googling" about this subject but can not find the solution...

I use **AVCaptureSession** to record video, and I see with a **AVMutableVideoComposition** I can insert a texte into a video with **animateTo** property. But I don't know how to add different texts to every AVAsset/ALAsset..

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can merge anything you want including frames and such. This tutorial will teach you how.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos